# Using the Newtype package

Tags: haskell

I'm very confused about how to use the [newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-0.2) package. Its documentation seems to hint that is very powerful, but I can't figure out how to use the functions provided (rather than the interface) to create some functions I need. For example, I'd like a functions with the signatures:

```
(Newtype n o) => (o -> o -> o) -> n -> n -> n

(Newtype n o, Functor f) => (o -> f o) -> n -> f n

(Newtype n o, Functor f) => (f o -> o) -> f n -> n
```

Writing these with combinations of `fmap`, `pack` and `unpack` is doable, but I'm hoping it's possible and cleaner with the mysterious `ala` or `ala'` functions (or slight variations that "lift" a function to the newtypes rather than "unlifting" them from newtypes). Should it matter, the functors I'm specifically interested in are `Maybe` and `[]`.

Comment: I believe the first one is best solved using `pack` and `unpack`, and with `Data.Function` and `Data.Composition` can be simply implemented with `f1 operator = pack .: on operator unpack`.  The other two are similarly simple: `f1 f = fmap pack . f . unpack` and `f3 f = pack . f . fmap unpack`.  In fact, `f2` and `f3` are halfway-between versions of `over` and `overF`, both of which are implemented with `pack` and `unpack` in the `newtype` package.  I'd follow the example of the authors and keep it simple.

Comment: Are there any downsides to making instances for `Newtype (Maybe n) (Maybe o)`, `Newtype [n] [o]` and `Newtype (o -> o') (n -> n')`?

Comment: Can you even define those instances in general?

Comment: For `Maybe` and `[]`, `pack = fmap pack` and `unpack = fmap unpack`. For the function, it's just `pack f = pack . f . unpack`. I think that's fairly general.

Comment: You can, but you have to turn on `UndecidableInstances` and add the constraint `Newtype n o`.  I think you'd be better served just using `fmap pack` over `Maybe o` than trying to force `Maybe o` to be castable to `Maybe n` directly using `pack`.  You'd end up having to put a lot of extra type signatures in your code because the compiler wouldn't be able to figure them out.

Comment: @bheklilr Can you give an example where inference would fail?

Comment: What is the type of `pack (Just 1)`?  Is it `Maybe (Sum Int)` or `First Int`? Personally I'd rather see `pack (Just 1)` being `First Int` and `fmap pack (Just 1)` being `Maybe (Sum Int)`, those concepts will be much more familiar to most Haskellers.  In the first you're converting a type to a corresponding newtype, in the second you're converting the type inside a functor to a corresponding newtype.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above, it seems there may be no clean way to write the functions I need using the hofs supplied by `Control.Newtype`. However, there seems to be another option: creating instances for *non*-newtypes.

An example with the [newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-0.2) package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances,
             FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Newtype

instance (Newtype n o) => Newtype [n] [o] where
  pack = map pack
  unpack = map unpack

instance (Newtype n o) => Newtype (Maybe n) (Maybe o) where
  pack = fmap pack
  unpack = fmap unpack

instance (Newtype n o, Newtype n' o') => Newtype (n -> n') (o -> o') where
  pack f = pack . f . unpack
  unpack f = unpack . f . pack

-- a newtype wrapper for Nums
newtype NNum a = NNum {unNNum :: a}
instance Newtype (NNum a) a where
  pack = NNum
  unpack = unNNum

ntimes5 :: (Num a) => NNum a -> NNum a
ntimes5 = pack sum . replicate 5

foo :: a -> Maybe [a]
foo = undefined

bar :: NNum a -> Maybe [NNum a]
bar = pack foo
```

As bheklilr mentioned, this requires `UndecidableInstances`, but it doesn't seem to require undue signatures. However, we can do better using the [newtype-generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics) package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DeriveGeneric #-}

import Control.Newtype
import GHC.Generics

instance (Newtype a) => Newtype [a] where
  type O [a] = [O a]
  pack = map pack
  unpack = map unpack

instance (Newtype a) => Newtype (Maybe a) where
  type O (Maybe a) = Maybe (O a)
  pack = fmap pack
  unpack = fmap unpack

instance (Newtype a, Newtype b) => Newtype (a -> b) where
  type O (a -> b) = (O a -> O b)
  pack f = pack . f . unpack
  unpack f = unpack . f . pack

newtype NNum a = NNum {unNNum :: a} deriving (Generic)
instance Newtype (NNum a)

ntimes5 :: (Num a) => NNum a -> NNum a
ntimes5 = pack sum . replicate 5

foo :: a -> Maybe [a]
foo = undefined

bar :: NNum a -> Maybe [NNum a]
bar = pack foo
```

(Of course you can always manually derive the `Newtype` instance here, too, saving on extension and one import.) Thus any issues that would have arisen due to `UndecidableInstances` or `FlexibleInstances` are now moot. The comparison of type families vs fundeps is summarized [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies_vs._type_families) and [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TFvsFD). This example seems to be a case where type families provide a clear win.